# Is there a way to change the volume increment on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, speakers

When I'm watching videos late at night I often turn the volume way down. I'm finding the iPhone volume increments from the physical push buttons are not very fine grained, it seems like a coarse big step between each button press. From mute to first audible sound I'd like something smaller in-between the two levels. I'd basically would like a smaller increment. Is there a way to control how sensitive the button is to volume adjustments?

---

By way of analogy I'm thinking of something analogous to what you typically see in a car stereo setting where the volume increment per volume knob adjustment is configurable.

To use a concrete example something like found in an Alpine stereo where you can adjust how loud the audio is from an Aux or Bluetooth device by controlling the decibel gain of the device from the UI.

> AUX VOL (AUX volume level) Adjusts the volume level for each connected
> auxiliary device: [+18 dB] – [0 dB] – [-8 dB]. This setting negates
> the need to adjust the volume level between sources. (Available only
> when the AUX is selected.)
>
> BTA VOL (BLUETOOTH audio volume level) Adjusts the volume level for each connected BLUETOOTH device:
> [+6 dB] – [0 dB] – [-6 dB]. This setting negates the need to adjust
> the volume level between sources. (Available only when the BT audio or
> Pandora® is selected.)

Comment: Somewhat overkill - but using a higher impedance headset would solve the issue. You can get TRS impedance adaptors quite easily, but TRRS I'm struggling to find.

Comment: Why don’t you use the volume control in control center : much more precise. You can also use Siri to set volume to 27.

Comment: @PtitXav hey that’s a great workaround. Post that as an answer as an alternative I’ll accept it. You’re right that is an alternate control route, pretty continuous too. In fact I should do a screen shot of the increments that show up there from physical button presses. Lay out the Siri workflow too I’ve never used that for volume control. I always use control center for brightness, I pretty much ignored the volume slider, gotta give that UI some attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don’t you use the volume control in control center : much more precise. You can also use Siri to set volume to 27.